# recently added a button alongside a react MUI dialog's textfield and the width of the textfield has reduced

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using MUI in react. I added a Button alongside a MUI Textfield and wrapped them in  and  with
to make the button and textfield sizes match.

This resulted in the length of the textfield being very short and I cannot find a way to make it fit its parent container width. (other than setting a pixel width value which kills responsiveness)

Any idea which element is governing the textfield's width?

The cascade of elements are:

```
<Dialog fullWidth>
 <DialogTitle>Hello</DialogTitle>
 <DialogContent>
   <Grid container>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item alignItems="stretch" style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <Button></Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogActions>
    <Button>Save</Button>
  </DialogActions>
<Dialog>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs, I used grid breakpoint properties:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/#fluid-grids

I applied xs={10} to the textfield and xs={2) to the two grid items.
I then applied 100% width to the button to make it fill its responsive parent.

```
<Dialog fullWidth>
 <DialogTitle>Hello</DialogTitle>
 <DialogContent>
   <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={10}>
        <TextField>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={2} alignItems="stretch" style={{display:"flex"}}>
        <Button style={{
         maxWidth: '100%',
         maxHeight: '100%',
         minWidth: '100%',
         minHeight: '100%'}}
       >inline</Button>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </DialogContent>
  <DialogActions>
    <Button>Save</Button>
  </DialogActions>
<Dialog>
```